# How connect by is really working? How is it multiplying rows?

Tags: oracle, hierarchy

I know (on high abstract level) how hierarchies in Oracle works, but this one I do not understand.
When issued following query:

```
select rownum-1 as num from dual
```

I've got one row as result.
The following query:

```
select rownum-1 as num from dual connect by level<=1000
```

is returning 1000 rows.
What is really happening in background of this query? How Oracle engine is multiplying rows when tries to resolve hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the standard SQL way of constructing a recursive query, you would see something like this:

```
with t (num) as (
  select rownum-1 num from dual 
  union all 
  select num+1 from t where num+1 < 10
) select * from t;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/4371/0

As you can see, it starts with selecting one row from the `DUAL` table, then recursively applying a `UNION ALL` to that single row while the limiting condition remains true. The `CONNECT BY` construct is just hiding this SQL plumbing from you.

If you click on the Execution Plan link in the fiddle above, you'll see that.